# Booting Tails from external hard drive

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails

Can I boot Tails from a external hard drive ( Ironkey H200 ), or only cd/usb ?

Answer (score 0):

no, i have tried to intall the TOR TAILS software onto an EHD, but it wont let you install it. Therefore if it cant be installed, then it cant be booted from.
Btw i used an ADATA 500gb drive.